# How to reset a Form in Flutter from another screen?

Tags: forms, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How to reset (clear) the form fields in flutter app? once the data is submitted to the server?

In my app, I'm having 2 pages.

1st page to enter the form details, like name, address etc

2nd page is to upload images.

1st page pushes the data to the 2nd page.
(Here I'm not doing push replacement, means 2nd page sits on top of first page)

2nd page is to select the images, and uploads the form data and images to the server.

**My Problem is**

*How to reset the all 2 pages, once the upload is complete?*

I'm using *firebase* server to upload my data!

Thanks, In advance

Comment: Can you please share how many fields are there in your 2 pages?

Comment: In 1st page 7 fields, and in 2nd page you can select up-to 3 images.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: example]

Use, for example, a `GlobalKey<FormState>` to access the form states and `reset()` the fields.
With this in mind, you can either:

1. pass in the constructor of the second screen the first form field
   key and reset both at the same time (when your data is done
   processing to the server or so)

---

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  final _formKeyScreen1 = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKeyScreen1,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Navigate to second screen...'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => Screen2(_formKeyScreen1),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> firstScreenFormKey;
  Screen2(this.firstScreenFormKey);
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  final _formKeyScreen2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _processData() {
    // Process your data and upload to server
    _formKeyScreen2.currentState?.reset();
    widget.firstScreenFormKey?.currentState?.reset();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKeyScreen2,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit data'),
                onPressed: () => _processData(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. or, you can reset the first screen form when the second screen pops from the stack, which IMO, should be enough since I believe you're not accessing the first screen form data from the second after processing, thus, if it's just for presentation purposes, resetting on return should be enough. In which case you'll end with the following

---

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  final _formKeyScreen1 = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKeyScreen1,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Navigate to second screen...'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Screen2(),
                      ))
                      .then((_) => _formKeyScreen1.currentState.reset());
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  final _formKeyScreen2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _processData() {
    // Process your data and upload to server
    _formKeyScreen2.currentState?.reset();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKeyScreen2,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              TextFormField(),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit data'),
                onPressed: () => _processData(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: _formKeyScreen2.currentState?.reset();   bro what are the question marks plz explain.

Comment: It’s [Darts null aware operator](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#conditional-property-access). That means that `reset()` will only be called if `currentState` is not `null`, preventing a null pointer exception.

Comment: Shouldn't reset() method to be called inside dispose() instead then() ?

Comment: @Fikret it's up to you. It should work both ways.

Comment: DON'T USE `reset()`!! It re-validated all fields (even by `onUserInteraction`!). Actually disposing and re-generating a new `GlobalKey<FormState>` is working better to "reset" the form!

Comment: Well maybe something have changed in the meantime. Last time I’ve looked it was a good (correct) approach, since reset would (like the method name suggests) reset all validations back to original state @Rebar.