# How to recreate a single widget in flutter and make it lose the state?

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful, statefulwidget

I have a widget that I want to recreate the state for what can I do to achieve this? I heard there is a way by `UniqueKey`s but I have no idea about them well because I'm a beginner (don't worry I have searched)

What I tried so far was to `pop` the `Navigator` and then `push` the same page again... And it works... But the problem is I'm losing the `BottomNavigationBar` when doing that as my page gets out of the state...

Here is my approach to solving this problem so far

```dart
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
```

`BottomNavigationBar`

```dart
int _selectedItem = 0;
  PageController pageController;

  void _onPageChanged(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedItem = pageIndex;
    });
  }

  void _onTapped(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedItem = pageIndex;
    });
    pageController.jumpToPage(pageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageController = PageController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        children: pages,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: bottomNavigationBarItems(context), // You can find this below
        currentIndex: _selectedItem,
        onTap: _onTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`bottomNavigationBarItems`

```dart
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> bottomNavigationBarItems(BuildContext context) {
  final AppLocalization translate = AppLocalization.of(context);
  final BottomNavigationBarItem homePage = BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.home),
    label: translate.translate('home'),
  );

  final BottomNavigationBarItem newsPage = BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.newspaper),
    label: translate.translate('news'),
  );

final BottomNavigationBarItem programsPage = BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.tv),
    label: translate.translate('programs'),
  );
 return [
    homePage,
    newsPage,
    programsPage,
  ];
}
```

Comment: Can you include your entire code with the BottomNavigationBar included?

Comment: @dshukertjr I did :) check again please

Comment: Can I see the entire widget from ''class'' to the closing bracket?

Comment: And which widget do you want to ''recreate and lose the state''?

Comment: See also: [How to reset a Form in Flutter from another screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986996/how-to-reset-a-form-in-flutter-from-another-screen)

Answer (score 2):

any widget give it

```
key: UniqueKey(),
```

will lose current states when setState called and rebuild again